Unrecognized Font Family 'Material Icons'
I am running into this error on my react native project when running it in the ios simulator: "Unrecognized font family: 'Material Icons'"
I have added the fonts into my info.plist file and added them into Copy Bundle Resources in my Targets in the xcodeproject. None of the other posts solutions work for me.
Please let me know what information would be valuable. Am very new to react native.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

RN supposed to do autolinking now, however it doesn't seem to work properly linked with react-native-vector-icons package. After the linking just install the ios/pod file using pod install.

delete build folder
npm i --save react-native-vector-icons
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
npm start -- -- reset-cache
react-native run-ios

